# Improve SQL Server query to convert arbitrary table to JSON

Tags: sql, sql-server, json, converters

After a lot of searching and piecing together the very excellent techniques for converting result sets using the FOR XML and .nodes() commands that are around the web, I was able to create this single query (not a stored procedure) which does a reasonably good job of converting any arbitrary SQL query to a JSON array.

The query will encode each data row as a single JSON object with a leading comma.
The data rows are wrapped by brackets and the whole result set is then expected to be exported to a file.

I'd like to see if anyone out there can see ways to improve its performance?

Here's the query with a sample table:

```
declare @xd table (col1 varchar(max), col2 int, col3 real, colNull int) 

insert into @xd 
select '', null, null, null
UNION ALL select 'ItemA', 123, 123.123, null
UNION ALL select 'ItemB', 456, 456.456, null
UNION ALL select '7890', 789, 789.789, null

select '[{}'
UNION ALL
select ',{' + STUFF((
    (select ','
        + '"' + r.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(max)') + '":'
        + case when r.value('./@xsi:nil', 'varchar(max)') = 'true' then 'null'
        when isnumeric(r.value('.', 'varchar(max)')) = 1
            then r.value('.', 'varchar(max)')
        else '"' + r.value('.', 'varchar(max)') + '"'
        end
    from rows.nodes('/row/*') as x(r) for xml path(''))
    ), 1, 1, '') + '}'
from (
    -- Arbitrary query goes here, (fields go where t.* is, table where @xd t is)
    select (select t.* for xml raw,type,elements XSINIL) rows
    from @xd t
) xd
UNION ALL
select ']'
```

My biggest critique of it, is that it's insanely slow.
It currently takes about 3:30 for ~42,000 rows.

My other big critique is that it currently assumes that everything that looks like a number is a number.  It doesn't try to discover column type in the least (and I'm not even sure if it can).

A final minor critique is that the first data row will have a comma up front and technically it shouldn't.  To compensate for that it requires that empty JSON object in the first row that starts the JSON array.

Other critiques (preferably with solutions) invited, the only real limitation I have is that the solution be decently repeatable on many arbitrary SQL queries without having to explicitly identify the column names.

I'm using SQL Server 2012.

Thanks and to anyone else like me who was looking for a generalized SQL Results -> JSON Array converter, ENJOY!

Comment: Whilst I applaud your SQL-fu, I have to ask: why? What is the scenario in the real world where you need to do this? I'm not trying to be negative here, just perplexed as to why you need this.

Comment: In this case I'm looking for an ad-hoc way to quickly load up result sets into NoSQL databases like CouchDB without having to build a lot of infrastructure or add anything to my production SQL environments.  Mongo, Couch, et al. seem to use JSON as their lingua franca for data transport.  Once in the NoSQL DB we can experiment with slicing and dicing the datasets to see how they perform.  Replicating CouchDB databases to create local repositories on remote desktops, laptops, smartphones, etc is way easier than managing a SQL replication infrastructure.  So we're doing some due diligence.

Comment: And let's not be too fooled here, most of that is found by searching for existing SQL to JSON and SQL to key/value pair answers.  Yes, I did put it together, put some brackets around it via UNION ALL, used a case statement to handle the quotes a bit smarter, and began trying with the XSINIL thing (and maybe I even learned how some of this is actually working ;) ) but I really can't take the credit for this. About the only thing I did newly was combine the sub query at the bottom to return each row as an XML dataset first before having the upper query turn it into key/value pairs.

Comment: Discovered that r.value('./@xsi:nil', 'varchar(max)') = 'true' will distinguish between whether or not the value was null (better than len() = 0 test I had before).  Updated original post to reflect the change.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I say if you really want to kick up performance, use metaprogramming.  The example below tries this with 40,000 rows and returns results in less than a second (not counting inserting the initial 40k rows, which in this example only takes about 2 seconds).  It also takes into account your data types to not enclose numbers in quotes.

```
declare @xd table (col1 varchar(max), col2 int, col3 real, colDate datetime, colNull int);

declare @i int = 0;

while @i < 10000 begin
    set @i += 1;
    insert into @xd
    select '', null, null, null, null
    union all select 'ItemA', 123, 123.123, getDate(), null
    union all select 'ItemB', 456, 456.456, getDate(), null
    union all select '7890', 789, 789.789, getDate(), null;
end;

select *
into #json_base
from (
    -- Insert SQL Statement here
    select * from @xd
) t;

declare @columns table (
    id int identity primary key,
    name sysname,
    datatype sysname,
    is_number bit,
    is_date bit);

insert into @columns(name, datatype, is_number, is_date)
select columns.name, types.name,
       case when number_types.name is not NULL
            then 1 else 0
       end as is_number,
       case when date_types.name is not NULL
            then 1 else 0
       end as is_date
from tempdb.sys.columns
join tempdb.sys.types
    on (columns.system_type_id = types.system_type_id)
left join (values ('int'), ('real'), ('numeric'),
                  ('decimal'), ('bigint'), ('tinyint')) as number_types(name)
    on (types.name = number_types.name)
left join (values ('date'), ('datetime'), ('datetime2'),
                  ('smalldatetime'), ('time'), ('datetimeoffset')) as date_types(name)
    on (types.name = date_types.name)
where object_id = OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#json_base');

declare @field_list varchar(max) = STUFF((
    select '+'',''+' + QUOTENAME(QUOTENAME(name, '"') + ':', '''')
           + '+' + case when is_number = 1
                        then 'COALESCE(LTRIM('
                                + QUOTENAME(name) + '),''null'')'
                        when is_date = 1
                        then 'COALESCE(QUOTENAME(LTRIM(convert(varchar(max), '
                                + QUOTENAME(name) + ', 126)),''"''),''null'')'
                        else 'COALESCE(QUOTENAME('
                                + QUOTENAME(name) + ',''"''),''null'')'
                   end
    from @columns
    for xml path('')),
    1, 5, '');

create table #json_result (
    id int identity primary key,
    line varchar(max));

declare @sql varchar(max) = REPLACE(
    'insert into #json_result '
  + 'select '',{''+{f}+''}'' '
  + 'from #json_base', '{f}', @field_list);

exec(@sql);

update #json_result
set line = STUFF(line, 1, 1, '')
where id = 1;

select '['
UNION ALL
select line
from #json_result
UNION ALL
select ']';

drop table #json_base;
drop table #json_result;
```

Comment: Nice. I knew I shouldn't have slept on it - this was the approach I was going to suggest as well. Could actually turn out to be very useful...

Comment: Nice as well!  Just 6 seconds on my actual table.  Another side effect though are dates are coming out as Feb  8 2013 12:00AM.  Let me look at that

Comment: Ok, I extended the solution on my side to add an "is_date" bit field, is it appropriate to adjust the original answer with my modifications before accepting? And thanks for showing me about joining to "values" I've never seen that technique before.  That's pretty cool!

Comment: Glad you liked it!  I think modifying to suit your needs is definitely the way to go.  Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I think this answer is pretty cool! And Stephen thanks to you to for being the first to take an interest in the question!  I modified this answer to reflect the final form, small tweaks to add exporting dates as ISO8601, adding the []'s, and making the "Put SQL Here" a bit clearer.  I like it! Much better than I thought I'd be able to get! Thanks!

Comment: For simplified reusability, I suggest wrapping it in a procedure.  You can use the `sysname` data type as the parameter accepting a table name to be used in the meta-SQL.  Unfortunately, it won't work with table variables, but you can just do the insert into a temp table before hand.

Comment: There's also passing in the SQL as a varchar(max) and then using exec like the answer Firoz posted does.  For now though, I prefer keeping the solution "footprintless" for this project. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From [Firoz Ansari](http://firozansari.com/2008/11/21/generating-json-from-tsql-query/):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetJSON] (
@ParameterSQL AS VARCHAR(MAX)
)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @XMLString VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @XML XML
DECLARE @Paramlist NVARCHAR(1000)
SET @Paramlist = N'@XML XML OUTPUT'
SET @SQL = 'WITH PrepareTable (XMLString) '
SET @SQL = @SQL + 'AS ( '
SET @SQL = @SQL + @ParameterSQL+ ' FOR XML RAW, TYPE, ELEMENTS '
SET @SQL = @SQL + ') '
SET @SQL = @SQL + 'SELECT @XML = XMLString FROM PrepareTable '
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, @Paramlist, @XML=@XML OUTPUT
SET @XMLString = CAST(@XML AS VARCHAR(MAX))

DECLARE @JSON VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Row VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @RowStart INT
DECLARE @RowEnd INT
DECLARE @FieldStart INT
DECLARE @FieldEnd INT
DECLARE @Key VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Value VARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE @StartRoot VARCHAR(100); SET @StartRoot = ''
DECLARE @EndRoot VARCHAR(100); SET @EndRoot = ''
DECLARE @StartField VARCHAR(100); SET @StartField = ''

SET @RowStart = CharIndex(@StartRoot, @XMLString, 0)
SET @JSON = ''
WHILE @RowStart &gt; 0
BEGIN
    SET @RowStart = @RowStart+Len(@StartRoot)
    SET @RowEnd = CharIndex(@EndRoot, @XMLString, @RowStart)
    SET @Row = SubString(@XMLString, @RowStart, @RowEnd-@RowStart)
    SET @JSON = @JSON+'{'

    -- for each row
    SET @FieldStart = CharIndex(@StartField, @Row, 0)
    WHILE @FieldStart &gt; 0
    BEGIN
        -- parse node key
        SET @FieldStart = @FieldStart+Len(@StartField)
        SET @FieldEnd = CharIndex(@EndField, @Row, @FieldStart)
        SET @Key = SubString(@Row, @FieldStart, @FieldEnd-@FieldStart)
        SET @JSON = @JSON+'"'+@Key+'":'

        -- parse node value
        SET @FieldStart = @FieldEnd+1
        SET @FieldEnd = CharIndex('0 SET @JSON = SubString(@JSON, 0, LEN(@JSON))
    SET @JSON = @JSON+'},'
    --/ for each row

    SET @RowStart = CharIndex(@StartRoot, @XMLString, @RowEnd)
END
IF LEN(@JSON) > 0 SET @JSON = SubString(@JSON, 0, LEN(@JSON))
SET @JSON = '[' + @JSON + ']'
SELECT @JSON
END
```

Comment: The problem/limitation with this approach is the results are limited to the @JSON varchar(max) string limitation.  So when the results get larger, the results start getting truncated.

Comment: BTW, thanks for this answer too even if I wasn't able to use it!