# SQL Server - Select column where at least one value is not null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to select all columns where at least one value is not null. For example :

```
TableUser
----------------------------
Name   |  Email  |  Phone
----------------------------
User1  |  NULL   |  123
User2  |  NULL   |  NULL
User3  |  NULL   |  NULL
```

Should produce

```
------------------
Name   |  Phone
------------------
User1  |  123
User2  |  NULL
User3  |  NULL
```

Is it possible to create a function to do it for you given a result set?

For example :

```
removeNull(SELECT * FROM TableUser WHERE Phone IS NOT NULL);
```

Comment: I think you're going to have to use `dynamic sql` for this since you don't know the number of columns you want to display.  This feels more like a presentation issue than a database issue though.

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to dynamically specify the columns to select. As sgeddes says, it's more of a presentation issue. Figuring out which columns that are empty is another matter though but I don't think that is what you want. Dynamic sql is the only way im aware of.

Comment: I think I found a good place to start from this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/14867847/3043529

Answer (score 1):

How to detect whether a given column has only the NULL value:

```
 SELECT 1 
      FROM tableuser
    HAVING COUNT(email) = 0 
           AND COUNT(*) > 0
```

The resultset will either consist of zero rows (column a has a non-NULL value) or one row (column a has only the NULL value).