# View without null columns

Tags: sql, database, datagrip

Is there a way to create a view of a table without the columns that are null.
What i mean by that is that i want a view where there are only columns where at least one row has some data in that column and is not empty.

[image: Example]

In this example, the result would be a view with columns **A** and **C**

I'm using Microsoft SQL and the data in db aren't going to be updated.

Comment: Your database is ?

Comment: The solution must be dynamic and you may need to create procedural sql for this. You can follow these links to get a solution,
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/98fdf8cc-80b9-4951-8d00-70957605a689/how-to-retreive-only-columns-which-having-at-least-one-not-null-value-in-any-row?forum=transactsql

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14865199/improve-sql-server-query-to-convert-arbitrary-table-to-json/14867847#14867847

Comment: Do you have the primary key column in that table?

Comment: @moscas yes i do

Comment: Ok, I made it wthout primary key

Answer (score 3):

That is not possible via the view, because the view cannot handle the dynamic column set. It is possible only via the stored procedure returning the result set. I made not a very beautiful and not generic decision, but I think you can upgrade it if you can.

First, we need to create a function which returns the set of columns which have at least one non-null value:

```
create function getTheColumnList() returns nvarchar(max) as
begin
declare @columnlist nvarchar(max);
set @columnlist = ''

declare @totalrows int;
set @totalrows = (select
                      count(*)
                  from table_name)

if (select
        count(*)
    from table_name
    where A is null) < @totalrows
    set @columnlist = @columnlist + 'A, '

if (select
        count(*)
    from table_name
    where B is null) < @totalrows
    set @columnlist = @columnlist + 'B, '

if (select
        count(*)
    from table_name
    where C is null) < @totalrows
    set @columnlist = @columnlist + 'C, '

set @columnlist = replace(@columnlist + '%', ', %', '')

return @columnlist;
end
go
```

Then we need to use this function in a dynamic SQL to construct the needed query. It can be done inside the stored procedure:

```
create proc getNottNullFromTableName as

declare @SQL nvarchar(1000)

declare @columnist varchar(50)
set @columnist = dbo.getTheColumnList();

set @SQL = 'SELECT ' + @columnist + ' FROM table_name';

exec (@SQL)
go
```

Finally, invoke that procedure:

[image]